# Display map after update from broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android, google-maps, broadcastreceiver

I'd like to update a map, after receiving the coordinates through a broadcast receiver.
So I send me a sms, the receiver got it, and put a marker on the map.
The problem is that the activity is not shown on screen : I've to switch manually to see it. The sms windows remains on the top. Any Idea ?

Besides, the marker isn't centered in the map...

Here is the code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private ArrayList<MyMarker> mMyMarkersArray = new ArrayList<MyMarker>();
    private HashMap<Marker, MyMarker> mMarkersHashMap;
    private  BroadcastReceiver updateReceiver =  new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {

            Log.e("DEBUG", "private broadcast" );
            Double longitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("long",0);
            Double latitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("lat",0);
            Log.e("DEBUG", "gotsms : " + longitude + " et " + latitude );

            mMarkersHashMap = new HashMap<Marker, MyMarker>();
            mMyMarkersArray.add(new MyMarker("I'm here", "icon1", latitude, longitude));

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            updateMap(intent, latLng);     
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(UPDATE_MAP);     
        registerReceiver(updateReceiver, filter);

        setUpMap();
    }

    protected void updateMap(Intent intent, LatLng latLng) {

        plotMarkers(mMyMarkersArray);

        CameraUpdate center=CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng);
        CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12);
        mMap.moveCamera(center);
        mMap.animateCamera(zoom);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should bring the activity to front on broadcast receive:

```
Intent intent = getIntent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
// add intent extras
startActivity(intent);
```

Starting another camera movement would override the first command so you should build a `CameraPosition` which does zoom and animate to position:

```
CameraPosition INIT = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(latLng)
        .zoom(zoomLevel)
        .build();
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(INIT), 250, null);
```

Comment: I've added that, but no changes. The sms sending windows remains on top :-(

Comment: You should probaby create a new broadcast receiver class which is not an activity and start the activity from there. Also don't forget to add it on the manifest.

Comment: Thanks for help. The camero position is now OK, but the activity still not on the front....

Answer (score 0):

After 2 hours, here is how I finally got it :

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent();
newIntent.setClassName("com.mypackage", "com.mypackage.MainActivity");
newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
context.startActivity(newIntent);
```

Comment: Hi how did you resolve this please? i'm stuck in the same issue